# Change child TextView colour on parent LinearLayout touch

Tags: android

I have a LinearLayout containing 2 TextView, one larger and black, one smaller and light grey. The LinearLayout's background is white by default then on touch quite a strong blue, and when it's touched (IE Blue), the grey text is lost in the colour, so I want to change it to white.

I've seen (using buttons) I can give textColor a resource file like this to change the text's colour

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#ffffff" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#000000" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#000000" />
    <item android:color="#ffffff" />
</selector>
```

Could I do something similar for my Layout/TextView? I thought about using an `OnTouchListener`, but the colour didn't change at the same time as the background did, and I've not found an onTouchEnd event yet to reset the colour back to grey.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can applicate `android:duplicateParentState="true"` to the two `TextView` into your `LinearLayout`.

Then, the click event will be propagate to the two child views.

Comment: My TextViews are added in Java, can I set duplicateParentState in java? EDIT: Found it, going to try this out now.

Comment: Yes, with yourTextView.setDuplicateParentStateEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a onTouchListener to the parent ==> Returning false from this call back ==> Also fetch all children of the parent in same call back ==> Cast them to TextViews and set text color ==> Call Parent.invalidate().

Comment: What does `invalidate()` do?

Comment: @TomHart Its Refresh your view.

Comment: It re-draws the UI element with new set of properties assigned to it.